# apache 2.4 name based virtualhost not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, virtualhost, apache2.4

I am using Amazon Ec2 and i have consolidated the 2 sites and need to setup different redirect rules for my old sites. but when i tried to the same with the below configuration, the web server always takes the first virtual host entry (site1.com) and not taking the second virtual host entry ( site2.com).
Can you check whether i am missing anything.

Please see below my config.

httpd.conf :

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen 0.0.0.0:443
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts-all.conf
```

httpd-vhosts-all.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName site1.com
  ServerAlias site1.com 
  DocumentRoot "/websites/site1"  
  <Directory /websites/site1 > 
    Require all granted
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>    
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule     ^/page1$  page2.html
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName site2.com 
  ServerAlias site2.com    
  DocumentRoot "/websites/site2" 
  <Directory /websites/site2 > 
    Require all granted
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory> 
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule     ^/page3$  page4.html
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks
Siva

Comment: what append when you go to http://site2.com/page3 ?

Comment: what's the verbatim URL you're testing?  Have you eliminated browser cache as a possibility?

Comment: if i use site2.com/page3 , it is going to 404 page . But if i put the same page3 url in the first virtual host it is working good. Basically i can have my redirect rules only for site1.com ( which is first virtual host )

Answer (score 2):

1. Would definitely try clearing your browser cache as covener mentioned... if you haven't already.
2. Make sure you can hit the intended rewrite target successfully?

http://site2.com/page4.html

3. If neither of those reveal the issue, you can add %v and %{host}i to your active LogFormat to confirm the incoming Host header value and which ServerName Apache is using. For example:

LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b **HOST=%{host}i ServerName=%v**"

Comment: Please see below my comments. 1) I have cleared the cache from the browser and it is not helping. 2) Also the individual target is working good. 3 ) apachectl -S  is listing 2 virtual host . 4) Sorry, Though i added the LogFormat , I didn't see any changes in my error_log file..  Also when i tried to add the site2 virtualhost as a first entry the /page3 started working  and /page1 stopped working. So somehow it is always taking the first virtual host entry in the httpd-vhost-all.conf file.

Comment: 1) Apache 2.4 is supposed to automatically enable Name based VHosting, but certainly wouldn't hurt to manually enable it as a test... i.e. adding the following line outside of the Vhosts:

NameVirtualHost *:80  
  
2) Not sure if you have anything sitting between the client and server, but might want to make sure nothing is converting / translating the hostname before it reaches the server. This is why I recommended adding the %{host}i to the LogFormat. This will show you the hostname of the request when it arrives at the server. And to clarify, the LogFormat is for the access_log.

Comment: :1) I have tried adding the NameVirutalhost *:80 and still having the same issue. 2) Also please see below the output log. The below one is for site2.com which still comes as site1.com
XX.XX- -[19/Jan/2016:13:37:31 -0500] "GET /page3 HTTP/1.1" 404 65854 HOST=site.com ServerName=site1.com
XX.XX- - [19/Jan/2016:13:37:32 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 65 HOST=site.com ServerName=site1.com
XX.XX - - [19/Jan/2016:13:37:32 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 - HOST=site.com ServerName=site1.com
XX.XX.X.XX - - [19/Jan/2016:13:37:33 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 65 HOST=site.com ServerName=site1.com

Comment: So it sounds like this a problem with the request hostname. Those requests are showing HOST=site.com, which is the Host header value on the request. "site.com" does not match either VHost's ServerName value, so Apache is just going with the first port 80 Vhost it finds. If you're requesting "site2.com" in the browser, then something is changing this to "site.com" before it reaches the server. Is the request going thru any intermediate devices? e.g. proxy, load balancer, gateway..etc.

Answer (score 1):

The first vhost is used by default if no other host is matched.

So you need to figure out why you are not matching the second host.

Are you perhaps using www.site2.com? That would fail to match the second vhost (which is only set up for site2.com without the www). I also don't understand why you have the same value set up in ServerName and ServerAlias? It's usual to have the preferred ServerName set up in the first and any alias's in the second (including the www version).

So instead of:

```
ServerName site1.com
ServerAlias site1.com
```

You would normally do:

```
ServerName site1.com
ServerAlias www.site1.com
```

You can also get a list of currently configured  vhosts using the following command:

```
apachectl -S
```

Other than that all I can suggest is looking for typos, ensuring Apache is restarted properly (but that seems to be ok since you can get it working when putting the 3->4 redirect in first instance), ensuring the host is being pased to Apache properly (e.g. If Apache is behind a proxy) and the page exists on site2 as per Brandon's suggestions and checking log files for errors.